# Is it possible to port-forward to a Unix domain socket using the permissions of a different user on the target host?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, port-forwarding, openssh

Consider a server X, which users A and B.

I have permissions to `ssh` as user `A`, and to `sudo` as user `B`, but I do not have permissions to `ssh` as user B.

There is a Unix domain socket with path `/path/to/socket` which is owned by user B.

I would like to port forward localhost port 7070 to `/path/to/socket`.
The first attempt is to the following:

```
ssh -L7070:/path/to/socket A@X
```

When I try to connect to localhost 7070, I get the expected permission error, because user A does not have permission to access the Unix domain socket.

```
 channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

There is a workaround using `socat` to translate a port into the socket, but it is insecure, because the server X is shared and other users logged into server X should not be able to connect to the port.

```
ssh -L7070:localhost:7070
sudo -iu B
socat tcp-listen:7070,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/path/to/socket
```

**Is there some option I can pass to ssh so that it will allow me to `sudo` as User B and grant the ssh server process permissions to connect to the Unix domain socket?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you literally have to `ssh B@X` for that to happen. The remote connections are made by the same sshd handler process that accepts your login – it does not use an external tool like nc/socat and therefore cannot "sudo" it.

Apply your `socat` workaround using a Unix socket instead of a TCP socket – use `unix-listen:` to establish a "middle" socket at a path only users A and B can access, and point the SSH tunnel to that.